# How do I add RIFF header to MP3 files programatically?

Tags: linux, perl, mp3, wav

More information about what I want to do here; http://www.studiodust.com/riffmp3.html

I want a way so that my control panel (made with Perl and Webmin) can do this automatically. Right now I have to rely on `system` calls and have a binary for Linux. Is there a library that does it for Perl or some other language?

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website I reference had the answer I needed. I didn't know they made a linux variant.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about RIFF files or their structure, uses, etc.  But [did you try searching CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=RIFF&mode=module)?  [The first result](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Format-RIFF/) looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following script for the exact thing you asked about.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "$1"
    ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -f wav out.wav > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
    normalize-audio -q out.wav && \
    lame --silent -a -m m --cbr -b 64 -q 0 out.wav out.mp3 && \
    ffmpeg -y -i out.mp3 -f wav -acodec copy "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
    echo "done."

    rm out.wav out.mp3
```

Just edit the parameters to lame or just use the ffmpeg call and you're set.